# Java class loader issue: only subset of classes from jar available

Tags: java, classloader

I am having some very odd problems loading a class by name using a class loader. This class is pulled in from a 3rd party jar, which is available on the class path. However, trying to instantiate the class fails with a ClassNotFoundException in the following line:

```
String className = "...";
myInstance = Class.forName(className).newInstance();
```

I have also tried with three different class loaders:

```
classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader(); // or 
classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader(); // or
classLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();

myInstance = (IPackageWriter)Class.forName(className, true, classLoader).newInstance();
```

None of this works, though. I examined the "classes" attribute and I do see some classes from that Jar, but not all of them. The one that I am trying to instantiate seems to be missing.

I have never across something like this before. Does anyone know why only a subset of the classes from a Jar might be available in the class loader? Or any ideas of how I could further debug this problem? 
Thanks a lot.

Cheers,

Martin

Comment: The "classes" attribute where?

Comment: The classloader object has a private member "classes", which I can examine in debug mode.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Not yet, anyways. I am working on other things right now, but when I get around to it, I will try to package a specific custom jar, which contains only the classes I really. Maybe it'll work that way...

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell what is your problem without seeing the class you are loading and the jar file. Here are a few things you may try to troubleshoot the problem, though:

1. Check out that your .jar file is not corrupted. Try unzipping it and make sure the class file is located in the right path.
2. Try loading the file without reflection, i.e. try instantiating it directly in the code and see if it fails.
3. If the previous step succeeded call

   ```
   CodeSource src = MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
   System.out.println(src);
   ```

   to find out from which jar it is actually loaded. It is possible that the class is being loaded from a different jar than you expect.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hints. 1: I have tried that and the class is there alright; 2: When instantiating the class directly, it works fine. 3: The class loaded exactly from where I would have expected it to be loaded from.

Comment: @martin_wun more hints: are you using full package name in class.forName() call? Does the class have a public no-argument constructor?

Comment: Yes, to both of these questions.